# android ListView ViewHolder and Type

Tags: android, listview, types, adapter

I want to have a Listview adapter where each rows uses it's own convertview, 
so this convertview couldn't be share to another row.
Basically, if I have 4 rows, I would like to have 4 convertview.
And when drawing the row #3 I should get the convertview #3

To do this I setted each row a different type (it's position)
I thought it would do the trick.

```
public class myadapter extends BaseAdapter {
final List<String> mdata;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mdata.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int p) {
    return p;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int p) {
    return p;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int p) {
    return p;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return mdata.size()  == 0  ? 1 :mdata.size() + 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int p, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (v == null) {
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.data, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder._pos = p;
        Log.v("TAG", "creating holder pos " + p + " for " + mdata.get(p));

        {...}

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        Log.d("TAG", "get convert for " + mdata.get(p)+ " holder " + holder._pos);

    }
    {...}
    return v;
}
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView _textView;
    public int _pos;
}
}
```

Note the pos in the viewholder is only here to debug purpose.

Unfortunatly it displays:

creating holder pos 0 for string0
creating holder pos 1 for string1
get convert for string0 holder 1
get convert for string0 holder 0
get convert for string1 holder 1

How the get convert for string0 holder 1 is possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,

```
getViewTypeCount()
```

could not change during the execution of the program.
You have to set it to a big value, even if you use less. It has to be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy paste your code and set following field ...

```
final List<String> mdata = Arrays.asList("s0", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9", "s10", "s11", "s12");
```

... iT works the exact way you would expect it.
Are you sure you didn't missunderstand the log output?